# Using Google Drive API to backup my app

Tags: java, android, database, google-drive-api

I would like to use the Google Drive API to backup my app data to the cloud. I have used `BackupAPI` before but am not satisfied with the results.

I have successfully integrated the library to my app.

I followed the steps in `https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/drive/sample/demo/CreateFileInAppFolderActivity.java`

I want to know how to copy my database for upload to Google Drive in `AppData` folder so that it is not visible to the user.

Need some help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Whatsapp. You might have noticed that it specifically asks the user regarding which google druve account the user wants data to be backed up. I dont think you can do it without letting the user know as far as I know.

But then again that is user data not app data. So it is different.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I would like some help in writing a code which uploads my database. Note: The user will be notified of this action.

Comment: I think this [SO ticket](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21984632/google-drive-to-back-up-and-restore-database-and-shared-preferences-of-android-a) can help you.

Comment: Thanks @KENdi. The above article helped me a lot.